# Display SQLite table data row by row in Android using TableLayout dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, tablelayout

I'm new to android coding. I simply want to display data row by row from my database table.

Here is the part where I have created database/table and added data.

```
    SQLiteDatabase glucoDB = openOrCreateDatabase("glucoDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    glucoDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Results(Timestamp VARCHAR, Level_using_hsv_range VARCHAR,Level_using_hsv_gradient VARCHAR,Level_using_lab_range VARCHAR,Level_using_lab_gradient VARCHAR);");
    String query=new String("INSERT INTO Results VALUES ('" + currentDateTimeString + "', '" + str + "mg/dL', '" + glucose[1] + "mg/dL', '" + gvalue + "-" + largeg + "mg/dL', '" + LabRes2 + "mg/dL');");
    glucoDB.execSQL(query);
```

Below is the activity code (ViewResults.java) for displaying database values.I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. On exporting and running the app, the rest of the app works fine but the part where data is displayed shows a black screen and app exits instantly. Although if I display data using simple TextView and not TableLayout, it is displayed normally. So database part is working fine, there's something wrong with my TableLayout code.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_page);
    int i=0,j=0;
    SQLiteDatabase Glucodb = openOrCreateDatabase("glucoDB",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    Cursor resultSet = Glucodb.rawQuery("Select * from Results",null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();

    TableLayout l1 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);
    l1.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    l1.bringToFront();

            do
            {   TableRow tr =  new TableRow(getBaseContext());

                    TextView t1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());                   
                    TextView t2 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                    TextView t3 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                    TextView t4 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                    TextView t5 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
                    t1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
                    t1.setText(resultSet.getString(0));
                    t2.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
                    t3.setText(resultSet.getString(2));
                    t4.setText(resultSet.getString(3));
                    t5.setText(resultSet.getString(5));

                    tr.addView(t1);
                    tr.addView(t2);
                    tr.addView(t3);
                    tr.addView(t4);
                    tr.addView(t5);

                l1.addView(tr);
            }while(resultSet.moveToNext()); 

        }
```

Below is the code of XML file associate with displaying results in table format.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

      <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
          >

        <TextView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Timestamp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gvalue1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gvalue2"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gvalue3"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gvalue4"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why haven't you set id for testviews and using those ids?why you are generating textviews dynamically

Comment: I'm fetching data from a table where the number of rows can be variant. Pardon me if I'm wrong, I'm new to android coding, but I don't really get you what will setting IDs make a difference in my case? I need a simple solution to print my SQL table data in a graphical table layout format.

Comment: @SarthakSinghal, please use listview to fill your database entries that will save you from coding a lot of useless lines. And that way you can optimize your code as well.

Comment: @PankajNimgade Hey can you provide me a link or sample code of how should I use listview to display data in multiple columns?

Comment: here is link to my project https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pk.nimgade.Bostan.Train.Schedule,

dex2jar it and you will get the entire code, you don't need to work so much with multiple columns just try to understand widgets

Comment: @PankajNimgade I was going through your app, couldn't really figure out which part of code should i find my solution in. It'll be really great if you could give me a small code example of ListView as per my problem.